# How to install / run service or command on host machine from a docker container

Tags: docker, containers

I'm trying to find a good way to run a command on a linux host machine from within a privileged docker container and I want the command to execute within the context of the host.

For example I want the ability to execute some auditing tool that scans the host. The tool is available inside the container and I want it to execute on the host.

Also, I'd like the ability to install a package on the host (specifically Auditd) from the container.

The container can be run with any privileges required for this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to use Docker here?  If your goal is to install software on the host, and generically "scan the host", an isolation layer that intentionally makes it hard to access the host isn't really what you want.

Comment: That's true. This is a constraint of the environment. The only way to get on the host is through a docker container..

Answer (score 1):

Installation:

- mount host FS into container (`-v /:/rootfs/`) and then run cp in the container, which will copy all required files to that mount /rootfs. Be carefull with dynamic linked binaries - they must be prepared for the host OS, not for container env (they may have different lib, glibc versions).

Management of host services:

- majority of Linuxes use systemd, so just mount required sockets into container (`-v /var/run/dbus:/var/run/dbus -v /run/systemd:/run/systemd`) and then systemd utilities (`systemctl`) from the container will be able to manage host systemd services

Comment: Hm.. is there a way to be able to run apt install from the container and have it install on the host ?

Comment: Hackish solution with chroot: chroot /rootfs <command on the "host">